# SetInterval running even after i clear it

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Im having a little trouble fixing a problem i have with setInterval.

I have a function that runs when i click an element on my website that sets var pass = 1;

if you look in color1(); there is a set Interval that clears itself when pass > 0; so if pass = 1; then it should clear itself, it does, but only after running the interval one more time.

so it - runs setInterval, clears setInterval, then runs the rest of the code in setInterval. What i need, is for setInterval to clear without running the code again.

Thanks in advance

```
function color1() {
      var pass = 1;
      var counter = 2;
      var animationSpeed = 800;

      var $colorContent = '.color-container-1 .color-content-container'

      var colorInterval = setInterval(function() {

        if (pass > 0) {
          clearInterval(colorInterval);
        }

        $($colorContent).fadeOut(0);
        $(($colorContent + '-' + counter)).fadeIn(animationSpeed);
        ++counter

        if (counter === $($colorContent).length + 1) {
          counter = 1;
        }

      }, 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like below, you should **`return`** the function. Here you have cleared the interval but you haven't stopped the execution

```
var colorInterval = setInterval(function() {

    if (pass > 0) {
      clearInterval(colorInterval);
      return; //stop here so that it doesn't continue to execute below code
    }

    $($colorContent).fadeOut(0);
    $(($colorContent + '-' + counter)).fadeIn(animationSpeed);
    ++counter

    if (counter === $($colorContent).length + 1) {
      counter = 1;
    }

  }, 3000);
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you! One of my first time using Stock Overflow, still getting used to how fast you can get a response! <3 :)